# Are Cogs supposed to be in the same code?

Tags: discord.py

I have seen a lot of things about cogs but I never understood if the cogs are supposed to be in the same code or in a different file. If it is in a different file, how do I load it in to main code file? I asked this question a lot of times and got millions of different answers. One answer which is supposed to work was `bot.load_extension('name')` but I have no idea what to substitute 'name' for. I tried writing the name of the cog file and the name of the cog, but PyCharm did accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m new to discord.py too but here i m sharing my little knowledge! [Sorry if i have some problems in my vocab!]

Cogs are like subclasses that helps you to organise your code and distribute your code in different sections, but still having a single bot and not to have a very long long code with different types of commands in a single file.
More Info At: [Discord.py Documentation For Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#:%7E:text=There%20comes%20a%20point%20in,Python%20class%20that%20subclasses%20commands.)

1. Create a folder named `cogs` in directory same as of your bot.py
2. To load and unload cogs using command you can use this code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

This will load cogs whenever you make one.

3. Create a cog example [example.py] in `cogs` folder.
4. You need to define class cog at beginning of every cog and define cog setup at end of every cog as such:

```py
import discord

class Example(commands.Cog): #Here Example is name of cog example.py

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


#Your code 
#Your code
#Your code


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example(client)) #Here Example is name of cog example.py
```

Just Use load command once if it doesnt load at first.
Cogs will automatically load as soon as you restart bot
or you can simply unload and load them by using `load [cogname]` and `unload [cogname]` command.

- `@client.event` changes to `@commands.Cog.listener` decorator
- `@client.commands` changes to `@commands.command` decorator

Please Forgive Me For Any Mistakes And Mislead ^^!

Credits : [A Simple Tutorial By Lucas On Youtube!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQw8cFfZPx0)

Comment: That how you do it yes. You could also add that `client` becomes `self.client` (or whatever you nammed it)

Comment: thanks, that is a different method than mine, but it actually works a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you need to put the cog file name with a '. So the cog is supposed to be in a different code and to load the cog file to the main file, you do `bot.load_extension('<cog-name>')`